# 403 frobidden when trying access apache / directory

Tags: linux, fedora, apache-httpd, php, apache-virtualhost

I am trying to run my first PHP code on my desktop Linux.

I installed httpd on my pc and changed these things:

Changed document root to `/home/MyUserName/httpd/www`

Changed default port to 8080

I run httpd as root and use my browser to access host (127.0.0.1:8080/)
But I get error 403 and I can't access any directories on the host.

My os is a desktop fedora 28.

Comment: You means started httpd service from root user? or means changed the USER variable in httpd.conf to root?

Comment: I use sudo to start httpd service
user variable is defualt

Comment: (Information) In that case your httpd server isn't started with root user, 
httpd always needs to start as root, then it uses setuid to switch to user context of specified user in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is you need to change the ownership of your customized document root so that it belongs to the `apache` user.

If you run..

```
ls -la /home/MyUserName/httpd/www
```

What do you get for the owner/permissions?

Try this...

```
chown apache:apache -R /home/MyUserName/httpd/www
```

That will recursively set ownership of your web root and anything contained below it to the `apache` user.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an SELinux Issue

If `getenforce` returns Enforcing, you could try temporarily disabling it ( until a reboot ) with `sudo setenforce  0`.

If you'r just trying to learn and don't feel you need this security feature you can permanently disable it in /etc/selinux/config by setting SELINUX=disabled

Note, disabling SELinux will stop protection system wide and not just for the Apache server. It wouldn't be recommended if your going for a secure environment. If it turns out to be the problem and you want to set it up right, you can look into `audit2allow` for IMO the quickest way to setup on a newly installed OS.